# Including typings for third-party library gives module not found via angular CLI?

Tags: angular, typescript, mapkit-js

I am attempting to include typings for Apple's MapKit JS in my Angular 9 application, because there are no high quality typings provided by the library, nor any good third-party typings in the `@types` scoped package. However, Angular CLI isn't happy with how I've included my typings. The exact error I receive on compile is:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'mapkit' in `components/map.component.ts`.
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Typings

### ~src/types/mapkit/index.d.ts

This is where the typings are declared, and how they are declared.

```js
declare module 'mapkit' {
  // interfaces, classes, etc here
}
```

## Typescript Configuration

### tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.app.json

```js
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

### Usage in code

Here is how `mapkit` is used.

```js
import * as mapkit from 'mapkit';
```

Comment: Did you tried installing typing by using this : npm install --save @types/apple-mapkit-js

Comment: @sunilbaba Those types are outdated.

Comment: You could create a pull request for @types/apple-mapkit-js. It may be a little bit more work now, but this way you would benefit from updates made by others in the future.

Comment: any custom types not in @types, need to be added to types in `compiler options`

Comment: Do you have webpack in your project?

Comment: It would really help if you can create a sample stackblitz or git repo for minimum reproduction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short: You need to rename your folder with types and add them to the type roots.

**Step #1**

In your folder with types (./types) create new folder "apple-mapkit-js"

**Step #2**

Add your custom index.d.ts there

**Step #3**
Point TSC to your custom types. Update tsconfig.app.json with new typeRoots:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "typeRoots" : ["./src/types/", "node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
}
```

**Step #4**
Update your import to the

```
import * as mapkit from 'apple-mapkit-js'
```

Now it works.

But what was the issue?

Actually, according to the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types), if you specify typeroots, all other resources become "invisible" for the typescript, so tsc just didn't see your declarations

P.S. Checked on the Angular 9 app.

Comment: Hi, I follow your method, and it is still not working, Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ros2d'

Comment: Hi @Chi this is probably another issue. Try to install ros2d directly using ```npm i ros2d @types/ros2d```

Comment: there's no @types/ros2d, so I need to add a typing for it

Comment: Check TypeScript version, (it was written for 3.5+), follow the instruction it should work. If complaints come from IDE, restart IDE. This also might help https://drag13.io/posts/custom-typings/index.html

Comment: @Chi and check if ros2d installed

Comment: I think I have found the issue, there's no module.export in this ros2d library, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a namespace instead

```
declare namespace mapkit {
```

and remove your import from your component

```
import * as mapkit from 'mapkit'; //Not needed
```

Since `tsconfig.app.json` already includes definition files from your project, your namespace declaration will work without further changes

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.d.ts"
],
```